Does this sequence have a next term?
The sequence is:
201343201353201923202238202234202319202341
A solution must consist of an explanation of the sequence.
Hint:

 Go to the website of B3/S23


rot13(guvf ybbxf yvxr lrnef naq znlor pnyraqne jrrxf, ohg jrrx svsgl-guerr va lrne guvegrra naq gur beqre bs guvegl-rvtug naq guvegl-sbhe va lrne gjragl-gjragl-gjb yrg zr qbhog nobhg vg.)

rot13(gur svefg sbhe qvtvgf ner lrne ahzoref ohg ab jrrx ahzoref ner hfrq)

This sequence represent

 The seven most recent discoveries of Important oscillators by period (related to Conway's Game of Life)

If you scroll down (on the given link I provided above and sort by year) you'll see this table:

   As you can see the numbers to the left (which represents the period) and the years corresponding to them match OP's sequence, in correct order. 2013 - 43, 53. 2019 - 23. 2022 - 34, 38. 2023 - 19, 41. And finding the last one, period of 41, proved that Conway's Game of Life is Omniperiodic  Edit: The periods 34 and 38 (in the image) in 2022 should switch place, to match the sequence, because 34 was discovered in July and 38 was discovered in January.

So, to answer OP's question

 No, this sequence doesn't have a next term.

The hint

 Was a reference to Conway's Game of Life: b3s23 means a cell is born if it has 3 adjacent cells, a cell survives if it has 2 or 3 adjacent cells

